# RecyclerView v23.2.0 and blank space after swiping up

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I updated the support library to 23.2.0. and changed the height of the recyclerView to wrap_content as explained in the blog [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.am/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) :

> The RecyclerView widget provides an advanced and flexible base for creating lists and grids as well as supporting animations. This release brings an exciting new feature to the LayoutManager API: auto-measurement! This allows a RecyclerView to size itself based on the size of its contents. This means that previously unavailable scenarios, such as using WRAP_CONTENT for a dimension of the RecyclerView, are now possible. You’ll find all built in LayoutManagers now support auto-measurement.
>
> Due to this change, make sure to double check the layout parameters of your item views: previously ignored layout parameters (such as MATCH_PARENT in the scroll direction) will now be fully respected.

edited/added comment : I had to do this because after the update  'match_parent' did what it's supposed to do, it stretched the cardviews height down to the bottom, so I ended up having one cardview per page.

But now after swiping up the newly created cardviews have the unwanted space between them again.

Let me clarify further :

- when the page is first loaded 5 cardviews are visible and they're being displayed correctly.
- I swipe up and a new cardview number 6 appears
- swiping up further makes cardview number 7 appear but there is blank space between number 6 and 7
- all newly created cardviews have a huge blank space between them

Has anyone encountered this behavior ?

Comment: Same here: v23.2.0 does this spacing, v.23.1.1 works just fine.

Comment: you can use WRAP_CONTENT in new update. Change MATCH_PARENT to WRAP_CONTENT in recycler view

Comment: it is. the problem is in the arrangements of the cardviews inside the recyclerview. as soon as I scroll things get messed up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the bug.

In the layout file where the cardview is in, I had to modify the surrounding RelativeLayout's layout_height attribute to WRAP_CONTENT as well.

Interesting part is, I changed the layout_height of RecyclerView back to MATCH_PARENT and it still worked as desired.