# RecyclerView items with big empty space after 23.2.0

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-support-library

After update to **v23.2.0** in my `RecyclerView` I have items with huge empty vertical space, between the items.

My item layout is very simple:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"                                    
       android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Comment: Still this error persist in 23.4.0 where i have nestedScrollView{ recyclerview . items()} when i remove few of those items meaning a sort would leave empty space sadly....

Comment: It's not an error, the expected behavior now. Related questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35677694/1009132), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35747268/1009132) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37504796/1009132)

Answer (score 134, accepted):

According to the [doc](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html)

> With the release **23.2.0** there is an exciting new feature to the LayoutManager API: **auto-measurement**!
>   This allows a `RecyclerView` to size itself based on the size of its contents. This means that previously unavailable scenarios, such as using **WRAP_CONTENT** for a dimension of the RecyclerView, are now possible.
>   You’ll find all built in LayoutManagers now support auto-measurement.

Due to this change, **make sure to double check the layout parameters** of your item views: **previously ignored layout parameters** (such as **MATCH_PARENT** in the scroll direction) will **now be fully respected**.

In your item layout you have to change:

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

with

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: My item layout was using a Constraint Layout which was causing some problems as well, switching that to a Linear Layout in accordance with the above answer solved my issue

Comment: @GabrielMoreno When I change the `layout_height` to `wrap_content` in my recyclerView and my imageView , images didn't appear

Answer (score 15):

You must make Recyclerview and item layout heights wrap content.

Comment: When I change the `layout_height` to `wrap_content` in my recyclerView and my imageView , images didn't appear

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I had made the new wrap_content changes but there was still a gap that manifested during onMove or onSwipe.  I solved that by adding this code:

```
mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().setMeasurementCacheEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is work for me.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:elevation="7dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="7dp"
    app:contentPadding="7dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_allfeedbacks_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_allfeedback_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_allfeedbacks_comment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_allfeedbacks_title"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_allfeedbacks_username"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            />
        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingbar_allfeedbacks"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            style="?attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
            />
        </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the given Solution worked.

Setting `layout_height = "wrap_content"` did not work either.

Parent layout of my list  design is **ConstraintLayout** and that was the problem(don't know what). But after changing parent layout to **RelativeLayout** everything work fine.