# android support design layout issue

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recyclerview, android-design-library

I have a Activity where I use `CardView` and  `RecyclerView`. Everything works fine. When I add   `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'`  to the gradle and run my app I get a lot of vertical spacing between my cardviews. Why is this happening.

Comment: Short answer is that there is some XML resource being overridden when you import the design library

Comment: is your `RecyclerView` wrap content

Comment: try this lib.. compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35728179/recyclerview-items-with-big-empty-space-after-23-2-0

Answer (score 0):

Before libs `23.2.0` in `RecyclerView` items you should use `match_parent` in height.

Since `23.2.0` you should use `wrap_content` for height of `RecyclerView` items.