# The distance between card view is too large

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, recyclerview-layout

I am using cardview with recycler view.But earlier I used the same code to do things without any problems.But now I am using fragments. Now I am getting the distance between the cardviews are greater.
my recycler view adapter

```
 public static class DataObjectHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        TextView label;
        TextView dateTime;
        ImageView imageView;
        ProgressBar progressBar;

        public DataObjectHolder(final View itemView, final Context activity, final ArrayList<DataObject> myDataset) {
            super(itemView);
            label = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            //dateTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thot);
            imageView=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.iproductimg);
            progressBar=(ProgressBar)itemView.findViewById(R.id.progress);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Adding Listener");
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myClickListenerhi.onItemClick(getLayoutPosition(),v);
        }
    }



    public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<DataObject> myDataset,MyClickListener myClickListener1) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
        activityContext=context;
        myClickListenerhi=myClickListener1;
    }

    @Override
    public DataObjectHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.cardview, parent, false);

        DataObjectHolder dataObjectHolder = new DataObjectHolder(view,activityContext,mDataset);
        return dataObjectHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final DataObjectHolder holder, int position) {
        Context context=null;
        holder.label.setText(mDataset.get(position).getmText1());
       // holder.dateTime.setText(mDataset.get(position).getmText2());
        Drawable placeholder = holder.imageView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.placeholder);
        holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(placeholder);
        //new ImageDownloaderTask(holder.imageView).execute(mDataset.get(position).getUrl());
        mDataset.get(position).setPosition(position);
            Picasso.with(activityContext)
                .load(mDataset.get(position).getUrl())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .into(holder.imageView, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                    }
                });
    }

    public void addItem(DataObject dataObj, int index) {
        mDataset.add(index, dataObj);
        notifyItemInserted(index);
    }

    public void deleteItem(int index) {
        mDataset.remove(index);
        notifyItemRemoved(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

    public interface MyClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position, View v);
    }

}
```

my cardview

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="3"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="156dp"
        android:layout_height="242dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="5dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:id="@+id/iproductimg"
                android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />
            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progress"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:indeterminate="false" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/firstheadtxt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

The error
[image]

Comment: which version are you using of recycler view?

Comment: Of course... but which version? 22.x.x ? 23.x.x ?

Comment: recyclerview-v7:23.2.1

Comment: @KBJ what he meant is which version of support library as of RecyclerView 23.2.1  is very much buggy

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35728179/recyclerview-items-with-big-empty-space-after-23-2-0. You are using match_parent in your w/h.

Comment: Thank you very much.It is working fine now..:)

Comment: But earlier cases I used match_parent.This issue was not appearing then.The issue comes now.I don't know what happend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this by changing `Cardview` `LinearLayout` attribute from

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

to

```
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

**Edit:**
Main problem is that the recyclerviews child layout or item layout rootview attribute is `match_parent`.

change it  attribut to `wrap_content`

```
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case : in the layout of cardview:

**remove** :`layout_margin="5dp"`

**add** :

```
margin_top = "3dp"
margin_left = "5dp"
margin_right = "5dp"
```