# Android Support Repository 23.2.1 RecyclerView error

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

After update my support libraries 23.2.1, I encountered a problem. Even I didn't change any code only library update, my recyclerview item's become not shown. Only first item shown, others not shown. I have no idea why it is not show all elements. Is there anybody encounters this problem and how to fix it?

**[Before library update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eu3yx.jpg)**

**[After library update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzZDg.png)**

Note: Unfortunaley I couldn't change my IDE Eclipse to Android Studio.

Comment: try clean and rebuild your project

Comment: This is the second post I have seen today with this sort of problem. Seems to be a bug.

Comment: I tried, didn't work. How to go back previous recyclerview library?

Comment: if you want to return back to previous library, in your `build.gradle` put `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'`

Comment: I am using Eclipse so I need downloadable link. As soon as possible I will change my IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a change in the support library 23.2.1

> RecyclerView.LayoutManager no longer ignores some
>   RecyclerView.LayoutParams settings, such as MATCH_PARENT in the scroll
>   direction. Note: These lifted restrictions may cause unexpected
>   behavior in your layouts. Make sure you specify the correct layout
>   parameters.

You need to change your layout items in your RecyclerView to use `WRAP_CONTENT`.

Comment: I change my xml however the output is very strange: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2JSOk.png

My xml code: http://codepaste.net/82e8z9
My cardview: http://codepaste.net/yzyn5s
My activity: http://codepaste.net/bdwxm4

Comment: You need to change the Linear layout that contains the cardview to WRAP_CONTENT instead of MATCH_PARENT

Comment: I changed like that but still same output: http://codepaste.net/91qqsn

Comment: It is each item to be added into the RecyclerView that needs to be WRAP_CONTENT. It is the layout xml file you have with a LinearLayout as the root item that you need to change, not in the activity layout file.

Comment: Finally I changed my xml as below and problem solved. Thank you sir!

xml of fragment: http://codepaste.net/zp6sz6
xml of childview: http://codepaste.net/okyph1