# RecycleView set wrong height for items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I search answer for me, but didn't find work answer for me. I got strange error in viewing my items in `RecycleView`:
[image]

I use different view's for RecycleView.

I try use this code:

```
mLayoutManager.setAutoMeasureEnabled(true); // false doesn't work too
```

But it doesn't help me.

**UPD 1** I forgot note this, sorry. When I start app, I have no errors (items like Normal on image) but when I started scroll my `RecycleView` I got problem)

**UPD 2** I return back to the  `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'`, but it doesn't help me (. So I add code and xml with mey `RecycleView` and I hope you help me.

XML:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/dashboard_recycle_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:scrollbars="none" />
```

And code:

```
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) parent.findViewById(R.id.dashboard_recycle_view);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    mLayoutManager.setAutoMeasureEnabled(false);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecycleAdapter);
```

Comment: what is the layout_height for your recyclerview?

Comment: @Amit Tiwari I use wrap_content. If i set match_parent I got this problem before scroll. Now, with wrap_content I get this problem when I start scroll

Comment: there was some problem with wrap_content in the earlier version of support library, but in the 23.2 version, they have fixed the wrap_content for height of recycler view. So, may be, there is still a bug in this version. Try setting your layout_height of recycler view to some static value like, say, 500dp and see if it working properly.

Comment: @AmitTiwari I cant set fix size, becouse I have different items in RecycleView ((((

Comment: You cant set different size for different viewtype.?

Comment: I am not asking you to set a hardcoded value for height, I am just asking you to set it once and test if it works as you want it to. By doing that, we you can identify the problem.

Comment: @AmitTiwari ok, I understand, sorry. I try it, but it doesn't work for me

Comment: I would then suggest to revert back to the older version of support library.

Comment: @AmitTiwari I revert back, but its problem doens't gone ((((((((

Comment: Oh, then I am out of ideas. See if someone can help, may be, put a bounty.

Comment: Have you tried to call setMeasurementCacheEnabled(false) on mLayoutManager?

Comment: @Alexey yes, I tried this

Comment: @Artem Did you get Solution?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set `wrap_content` for the recyclerview and for your viewholder layout parent.
This worked for me.

Comment: using a RelativeLayout with android:layout_height="wrap_content" is still not showing the content of my nested recyclerview.  If I set a height, the items display no problem.

Answer (score 4):

Set `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent` ( if you set as `match_parent` ) as that causes the layout to match the parent giving you the large spaces.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem. If you only change `RecyclerView` to `wrap_content`, the startup page looks fine but you will get blank space after swiping up.

**Solution:**
In addition to change `android:layout_height` of `RecyclerView` to `wrap_content`, you should also go to the layout XML file where your `RecyclerView` items are, and modify the surrounding RelativeLayout's `android:layout_height` attribute to `wrap_content`.

Please refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35677694/recyclerview-v23-2-0-and-blank-space-after-swiping-up).