# RecyclerView 23.2.x height=0dp causes onBind called for all items and scrollToPosition not working

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-recyclerview

**UPDATE**
I just updated the support library to `23.3.0` and this problem does not seem to happen any more. I suppose this was a bug in the `23.2.X` version. Well, this is not the first time that I have spent hours on a weird problem, and then later found that it was a bug of the Android SDK.
**END UPDATE**

In the following code, I set `layout_height="0dp"` and `layout_weight="1"` to the recycler view to make it fill the remaining space of a linear layout. It looks to me that layout_height would not be needed because layout_weight is set, but omitting that attribute is considered an error, and examples I found in other questions on Stack Overflow suggest using "0dp".

The strange thing is that if I set layout_height="0dp", onBindViewHolder() is called for all items at once. That is, the debug output is like

```
onBindViewHolder(0)
...
onBindViewHolder(99)
```

If I set layout_height="1dp", onBindViewHolder() is called for only the first several items until scrolled. That is, the debug output is like

```
onBindViewHolder(0)
...
onBindViewHolder(8)
```

This does not happen with RecyclerView version 23.1.1, but happens with version 23.2.0 and 23.2.1 (e.g., `com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1`), and it also makes the programatic scrolling not working. Why is it so? Am I supposed to use "1dp" in this case?

The following are the entire source codes.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    />

<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff111111"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp">

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/mylist"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp">
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

my_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:clickable="true"
          android:focusable="true"
          android:id="@+id/itemRect"
          android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
    android:layout_width="48sp"
    android:layout_height="48sp"/>
<TextView
    tools:text="Hello world"
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="48sp"/>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
String TAG = this.getClass().getName();
RecyclerView mylist;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mylist = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.mylist);

    ArrayList<String> source = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i =0; i< 100; i++)
    {
        source.add("List item " + i);
    }

    LinearLayoutManager lay = new LinearLayoutManager(mylist.getContext());
    mylist.setLayoutManager(lay);
    MyAdapter adap = new MyAdapter(source);
    mylist.setAdapter(adap);
}


class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    TextView name;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    }

    public void bind(String item)
    {
        name.setText(item);
    }
}
class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>
{
    List<String> items;
    public MyAdapter(List<String> items)
    {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_item, null);
        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder(" + position + ")");
        holder.bind(items.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return items.size();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are looking for. If height is 100, then inorder to distribute it in two components . First 40% and second by 60%. This should be the way. layout_height="0dp" and layout_weight="0.40" For First and layout_height="0dp" and layout_weight="0.60" for second component

Comment: Look at accepted answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35747268/recycleview-set-wrong-height-for-items

Comment: Same bug is on 24.2.1 version. RecyclerView heightSpec is 0 so [android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager#resolveIsInfinite] is true so. I had to change layout_width from "0dp" to "match_parent" for my recyclerview with layout_weight=1. in horiznontal LinearLayout , otherwise onBind will we called for every item.